# Question About Euclidean Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove the following three statements:

"Let $D$ be a euclidean domain with norm $N$, such that $N(a) \leq N(ab)$ for all nonzero $a,b \in D$.
(1) Prove that $N(a) \geq N(1)$ for all nonzero $a \in D$.
(2) Prove that an element $a \in D$ is a unit if and only if $N(a)=N(1)$.
(3) Suppose that $D=\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Prove that $N(a) \leq N(ab)$ for all nonzero $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$." In this case, $N(a)=|a|^2$.

Could anyone walk me through how to prove these?

Comment: Surely you can at least do question (1), right?

Comment: I feel like it should be trivial, but I just recently started learning about this, so I don't really know where to go with the proof.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
N(1) & \le N(1b) = N(b) \\[6pt]
\text{So } N(b) & \le N(b) \text{ for every } b\in D.
\end{align}
That takes care of question $1.$

$a\in D$ is a unit precisely if for some $b\in D$ you have $ab=1.$ So then you have
\begin{align}
N(1) & \le N(a) & & \text{by the result of question 1} \\[6pt]
& \le N(ab) & & \text{(This was given at the outset.)} \\[6pt]
& \le N(1) & & \text{since } ab=1.
\end{align}
That finishes off question $2.$

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! Can you help me with question 3 at all?

Comment: @bzoll213 : Question 3 is unclear since is doesn't say what function $N$ is in that case.

Comment: $N$ should be $|a|^2$, my bad.

Comment: @bzoll213 : If $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb R$ then $N((p+qi)(r+si))$ $= N((pr-qs) + i (ps+rq))$ $ = (pr-qs)^2 + (ps+rq)^2 $ $ = (p^2+q^2)(r^2+s^2) $ $ = N(p+qi) N(r+si). $ If $p,q,r,s\in\mathbb Z,$ then all of the values of $N$ except $0$ are${} \ge 1.$ Multiplying by something${}\ge1$ does not lessen its magnitude. $\qquad$